# Display items in a listbox on one row in multiple columns - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I have a listbox that gathers the field names of a table, the problem is it displays the fields like this:

```
Field 1
Field 2
Field 3
```

Whereas I want it to display them like they are displayed in the table, like this:

```
Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3
```

I changed the column count to 3, in order to get the columns; but it then displays the results like this:

```
Field 1 | Field 1 | Field 1
Field 2 | Field 2 | Field 2
Field 3 | Field 3 | Field 3
```

It's probably a simple fix, but I don't know what I'm looking for. If I can't use a listbox to do this, do you have any other suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Setting the listbox RowSource type to 'Table/Query' displays the results of each field correctly; but setting the RowSource to 'Field List' won't display the field names correctly

Answer (score 1):

I changed the ListBox 'ColumnHeads' property to 'Yes'; which successfully displayed the Column names and fields in the required format.

```
Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3
```